# I can't figure out a formula with nested if in Excel

Tags: excel

Hello I would like to realize in excel the following formula:
if D5 is equal to "yes" and if g5 is between 5 and 8, we have 50
if D5 is equal to "yes" and if g5 is between 9 and 11, we have 65
if D5 is equal to "yes" and if g5 is between 12 and 15, we have 75
and in case D5 is equal to no, we return 0

My formula is:

```
=SI(D5="OUI";SI((ET(G5>=5;G5<=8));"50";SI((ET(G5>=9;G5<=11));"65";SI((ET(G5<=12;G5<=15));"75";"0"))))
```

but my problem is when D5 is no, we return False and not 0

Answer (score 2):

One more option:

```
=LOOKUP(G1;{0;5;9;12;16};{0;50;65;75;0})*(D1="yes")
```

Replace semicolons with commas if needed

[image]

Comment: Very Cool! Took me a while to get the logic though.

Answer (score 1):

In order to clarify this formula, I have rewritten it in pseudo-C:

```
if (d5 == "OUI")
{
    if (g5 >= 5 && g5 <= 8)
        return 50;
    else if (g5 >= 9 && g5 <= 11)
        return 65;
    else if (g5 >= 12 && g5 <= 15)
        return 75;
}
```

In this form, it's clearer that the result is undefined if d5 is anything other than "OUI", if `g5 < 5`, or if `g5 > 15`. You actually want to return 0 in those cases, right?

Excel's IF function is strangely nonorthogonal if you don't provide an ELSE argument: It returns FALSE when the first argument is false. For example:

```
IF(FALSE, 1, 2)    returns 1
IF(FALSE, 1)       returns FALSE
IF(TRUE, 1, 2)     returns 1
IF(TRUE, 1)        returns 1
```

And I don't think you want that.

So I would recommend rewriting to add an ELSE "0" after the "75" and after the main IF. In pseudo-C:

```
if (d5 == "oui")
{
    if (g5 >= 5 && g5 <= 8)
        return 50;
    else if (g5 >= 9 && g5 <= 11)
        return 65;
    else if (g5 >= 12 && g5 <= 15)
        return 75;
    else               // new
        return 0;      // new
}
else                   // new
    return 0;          // new
```

And back in the original format, like this:

```
=SI(D5="OUI";SI((ET(G5>=5;G5<=8));"50";SI((ET(G5>=9;G5<=11));"65";SI((ET(G5>=12;G5<=15));"75";"0")));"0")
```

One last point. In undergoing this exercise, I also noticed that your final condition, `G5<=12;G5<=15`, is wrong. You wanted `G5>=12;G5<=15`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that also returns zero if G5 is less than 5 or greater than 15. It also covers "yes" in any case configuration, e.g. Yes, YES, yes, yEs, etc.

```
=IF(UPPER(D5)<>"YES",0,IF(G5<5,0,IF(G5<9,50,IF(G5<12,65,IF(G5<16,75,0)))))
```

HTH